# Firebase - For item in directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data in a directory and I want to retrieve the value of a certain object e.g. Get the value of "NVR".

[image: Data]

---

Another task I need to do is have a 'for' loop to go over and get information about different questions from the following data. I would need to get the number e.g. "001" and the items inside of that subdirectory. And it would also need to go through every directory in 'questions' such as NVR or MTH.

[image: data 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, you can try this:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("unique").on('value', function(snapshot) {
var datas = snapshot.val();
var nvr=datas.NVR;
)};
```

For the second one try this:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("questions").child("NVR").on('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var keys=child.key;
var datas = child.val();
var correcta=child.val().correctAnswer;
var num=child.val().numberOfAnswers;
     //etc
 });
});
```

the first one the snapshot will be at `unique`, then you will be able to retrieve the child `NVR`.

In the second one, you iterate inside `NVR` and retrieve the key using `var keys=child.key;`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for going through every directory in `questions` and for each one getting all the questions in it :

```
firebase.database.ref('questions').on('value').then((snapshots) => {
   //print whole questions group (nvr, mth, etc)
   console.log(snapshots.val())
   snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
      //print each question in question group
      console.log(snapshot.val())
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Peter's and Egor's answers load all data under `unique`. Since you know the key of the item whose value you want to retrieve, you can load this more efficiently with:

```
firebase.database().ref("unique/NVR").on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var nvr=snapshot.val();
)};
```